# What is this icon and what does it do?

Tags: files

I am new in using Ubuntu (coming from Linux Mint), so I don't know the purpose of this icon on the home screen. Could someone explain it to me. Thanks ahead.

[image: what is this?]

Comment: Your google drive?

Comment: Thank you, I guess it just something that I didn't realize I put it in here. Merry Christmas.